# Windows 10 updated Edge Unfeatures Bing Look Up

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

I had gotten used to right-clicking a selected word and looking up its definition. This feature is gone now ... Can I bring it back?

About this app says: *Microsoft Edge 38.14393.0.0*.

Comment: I think this has been replaced with 'Ask Cortana'. Which gives a similar same result.

Comment: @mt025 Affirmative. I just had to system-reenable Cortana.